# How to install neo4j-shell-tools with Neo4j Desktop

Tags: neo4j, graphml, neo4j-shell, neo4j-desktop

I'm trying to install neo4j-shell-tools on windows running the neo4j desktop. After unzipping and placing the folder in the LIB directory and restarting, it doesn't seem to load the tools?

```
Invalid input 'm': expected 'n/N' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
"import-graphml"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**neo4j-shell is deprecated**, so I suggest you to not use it !
Instead, you should use the **cypher-shell**.

Moreover, to achieve what you want to with **neo4j-shell-tool** with **cypher-shell**, you should use **APOC** : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures

**APOC** has all the features that has **neo4j-shell-tool**, and you can direclty install it in one click on the desktop edition.

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this and you're right, the future and answers is with APOC.